# Possibly false theorem in a book. Quine's theorem proof. A.k.a. Blake's method for reducing boolean functions.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-explanation, boolean-algebra

This is what I found in one text on discrete mathematics:

**Theorem:** *given **a full DNF** of a boolean function, if we first simplify it using all identities of the **type 1**: $(x\land y)\lor (\bar{x}\land y) = y$ and $(x\lor y)\land (\bar{x}\lor y) = y$, and then apply all **absorptions** $(x\land y)\lor y = y$ and $(x\lor y)\land y = y$, we get a **reduced DNF**, namely the disjunction of all its prime implicates.*

The text contained a "proof", but it was way too handwavy and actually similar to what I`ll describe below.

Here is my intuition of the proof: if we multiply a prime implicant by the expression of the type $(x\lor \bar{x})$, we can turn it into a disjunction of minterms. This way we can get a full DNF. Since then by applying to our full DNF operations of the type 1, which are inverse operations to multiplying by $(x\lor \bar{x})$, we should get all prime implicants. But there also will be some additional unwanted terms, that our absorbtions *should* take care of.

My question is how can I justify all the above steps and turn it into a complete rigorous proof?

Actually, I don`t even think the theorem as stated above is true at all. We probably need a more advanced identity - $$(a\land c)\lor (b\land \bar{c})=(a\land c)\lor (b\land \bar{c})\lor ab$$ for the first step instead of those of type 1 described in the theorem.

Comment: Hmm, I would use K-maps as a guide for such a proof. The equivalence of type 1 is called Adjacency, and if you look at a K-map you see why: Adjacency takes (groups of) 1s that are adjacent and combines them into larger groups, thus eventually resulting into prime implicants. And Absorption gets rid of redundancies: absorbing (groups of) 1s into larger groups. As for the equivalence you state at the end: that one is called the Consensus Theorem and can be derived using Adjacency and Idenpotence: $ac+bc’=abc+ab’c+abc’+a’bc’=abc+abc+ab’c+abc’+abc’+a’bc’=abc+abc’+abc+ab’c+abc’+a’bc’=ab+ac+bc’$

Comment: But yeah, that means you do need Idempotence … so I think you are right: Adjacency and Absorption are not sufficient!

Comment: However, Adjacency and Idempotence together should be sufficient: Adjacency allows you to group together any groups of 1s, and break any groups down again so you can group in any which way you want … and any redundancies can be taken care of by Idempotence. Of course, you may not like that as a hard enough proof, but it makes total sense to me from a K-map point if view :P Indeed, Absorption can be done by Adjacency and Idempotence: $a+ab= ab+ab’+ab= ab+ab’=a$