# Proof of Karnaugh(k-map) method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

How to prove that by grouping the largest number of 1`s in a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) one can always get a minimal DNF?

I understand that it reduces the number of symbols, but I can`t show the above fact is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&1\\
\hline
&1&1&1\\
\hline
1&1&1\\
\hline
&&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: I see. The minimal DNF obtained by Quine's method has 2 symbols less, right? Actually, I suspected that this fact wasn't true, but couldn't find a proper counterexample. So many books simply use it as a method of finding a minimal DNF, never mentioning that this isn't always the case 

Comment: @Sgg8 I loved your question! Yes, the books always say to find the largest groups but I had never questioned whether this would actually always lead to the very minimal one. And the counterexample immediately popped into my head :P I also love proofs by picture … so this was my first disproof by picture :)

Comment: I really hate seeing something stated without a proof. Memorization of some algorithms has nothing to do with math and can only lead to claims like this in almost every text that mentions k-maps. I also asked a similar question regarding Quine's method recently here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4458911/732945. Look that up if you're interested, no one has answered yet :(

Comment: @Sgg8 Just added a comment to that other post

Comment: More specifically, 1. K-map will have 5 terms for the OR gate and Quine's method has 4. 2. K-map is a bit like the greedy algorithm which thinks *from the biggest block to the smallest*, not ensuring one optimal solution. But Quine's method thinks *from the smallest block to the biggest*, so they may differ a lot.